# Get value from app.config file using library standard 2.0 return null

Tags: app-config, .net-standard-2.0

I try to get the value from the app.config file which I just created in library standard 2.0. But it returns a null value

Here is my code which write my code using the same library,

```
public static string Url
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlLink"];
        }
    }
```